# Send data efficiently without band saturation (iOS)

Tags: ios, throttling

I'm working on logger system which should send messages from the local device (an iOS device but generally any other mobile OS) to an endpoint over the network (not necessary on the same LAN, it should work fine even through the network).
How can I send these data efficiently? Is there any algorithm I can use to avoid congestion of the bandwidth (some throttling?)

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing load on Network is done with following methods.

1. Keeping messages/data locally once received, (Caching)
2. Sending compressed data over network
3. Paging, Sending data in the form of pages, and next page load on demand. (Like I want to see the chat history with you, Only last 20 messages will load, Once I reached the oldest message, it should load next 20 messages and so on)